# Calculate probability density by function application

Tags: density-function, function, application

let's assume we have a probability density function which is $$f(X) = \frac{a}{x^a+1}$$

how can we calculate something like this: $$Y = ln(X)$$

Comment: What is the range of the parameter $a$ and what is the support of $f$? To compute the density of $Y$ you can take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#Function_of_random_variables_and_change_of_variables_in_the_probability_density_function and try by replacing $g(x)$ with $\ln(x)$.

Comment: @winperikle Thanks for your attention, the range of $a$ is the positive numbers. and many thanks for the link.